Ensuring an environment takes at least a given amount of vertical space
I am trying to define an environment that displays some symbol at the start of some content. This symbol may take multiple lines, and I want this to push down the content that comes after the environment, but without pushing down the second line of the environment content.
A MWE :
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{mm}
 {\par\makebox[0pt][r]{\vtop{\hbox{\bfseries #1\ }\hbox{\itshape #2\ }}}\ignorespaces}
 {\par\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}


\begin{question}{arfze}{b}
test
\end{question}

bla

\bigskip

\begin{question}{arfze}{b}
test test test test test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test
\end{question}

bli

\end{document}


This correctly pushes down "bla" in the first instance, but creates disruption in the long paragraph of the second instance. Conversely, I could type set the initial mark in a zero-height box, which would let the content of the second instance be typeset naturally, but would make "bla" come too high.
Another question tries to achieve something similar, but I am not sure the solution is adaptable to my needs, because I have not yet been able to really understand how \prevgraf works, and also because, contrary to them, I need the environment content to not be typeset in a box (it may span across pages or contain floats).
I am open to solutions using LaTeX3 (coffins ?) and/or lua.

Do you expect that the label in the margin takes more than two lines? The definition you give doesn't really allow it.

In principle, yes. The MWE is a simplified version of the problem. But I can typeset the thing in a box to get its height, see my answer below.

Samcarter's answer led me to look into tikz' remember picture, which allowed me to learn, in an answer to another question, about zref, which has commands to store the position-on-page of an element.
We need to create a zref-label to remember the position of each beginning and end of question environment. Because positions are only within a page, we also need to remember on which page is each part, so we can compute and add the needed vertical space, but only if both ends of the environment are on the same page.
I used an integer counter to generate different labels for each instance of {question}, maybe there is a more elegant way.
We start with
\RequirePackage{zref-savepos, zref-user}
\box_new:N \g__chato_exo_question_box
\dim_new:N \g__chato_exo_question_box_ht
\int_new:N \g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber
\dim_new:N \l_debut_dim
\dim_new:N \l_fin_dim
\int_new:N \l_debut_page
\int_new:N \l_fin_page

The box will receive the content to be displayed at the beginning of the question. Its height will be set to zero, after having stored in \g__chato_exo_question_box_ht the vertical space of the part that is dangling below the first line. We also store the page and position. This is done with the following command.
\cs_new:Nn \cs__chato_exo_question_symbs:nn {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
  \vbox_gset:Nn \g__chato_exo_question_box
   {
    \hbox_to_zero:n { \hss #1 }
    \offinterlineskip
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \vskip1mm
      \hbox_to_zero:n {\hss \hbox_to_wd:nn {1em}{ \hss ##1 \hss}}
     }
   }
   %% The above is specific to my layout, the below is what the present answer si about :
   \dim_gset:Nn \g__chato_exo_question_box_ht {\box_ht:N \g__chato_exo_question_box - \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box}
   \int_gincr:N \g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber
   \exp_args:No\zsaveposy{chato-exo-question-posy-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}
   \exp_args:No\zlabel{chato-exo-question-page-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}
   \box_gset_ht:Nn \g__chato_exo_question_box { \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box  }
 }

This command is called at the beginning of the environment, with the 1st argument being the number of the question proper, and the 2nd being a list of symbols to display below it (these symbols are what creates the problem !).
At the end of the environment, we again store where we currently are, and (on the next LaTeX run, because this goes through the aux file), we will be able to compute if additional vertical space is needed.
  \par
  \exp_args:No\zsaveposy{chato-exo-endquestion-posy-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}
  \exp_args:No\zlabel{chato-exo-endquestion-page-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}
  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_debut_page {\exp_args:No\zref@extractdefault{chato-exo-question-page-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}{page}{0}}
  \exp_args:NNx \int_set:Nn \l_fin_page {\exp_args:No\zref@extractdefault{chato-exo-endquestion-page-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}{page}{0}}
  \int_compare:nNnT {\l_debut_page} = {\l_fin_page}
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_debut_dim {\zref@extractdefault{chato-exo-question-posy-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}{posy}{0}sp}
    \dim_sub:Nn \l_debut_dim {\g__chato_exo_question_box_ht}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_fin_dim {\zref@extractdefault{chato-exo-endquestion-posy-\int_use:N\g__chato_exo_zref_qnumber}{posy}{0}sp}
    \dim_compare:nNnT \l_debut_dim < \l_fin_dim
      {\vspace*{\dim_eval:n{\l_fin_dim - \l_debut_dim}}}
  }

I may have overdid it with the \exp_args, but it is important to use zref's internal command \zref@extractdefault to avoid errors on the first LaTeX run, when \zpos and \zpage will return nonsense. Also note the computation are a bit bizarre because the position are denoted from the bottom up.

You could use a tcolorbox:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{question}[2]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  attach title to upper=~,
  title=\hskip-0.5cm #1,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  height from=5cm to 8m,
  left=0.5cm,
  overlay unbroken={\node[anchor=north west,text width=0.5cm] at ([yshift=-1.6\baselineskip]frame.north west) {#2}; },
  overlay first={\node[anchor=north west,text width=0.5cm] at ([yshift=-1.6\baselineskip]frame.north west) {#2}; },
  interior hidden,
  frame hidden
}

\begin{document}


\begin{question}{arfze}{b}
test
\end{question}

bla

\bigskip

\begin{question}{arfze}{b}
test test test test test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test
\lipsum
\end{question}

bli

\end{document}


Thanks for the idea, but introducing tcolorbox breaks so many other things in my layout that it does not seem feasible. BTW, the documentation states that height control keys are only intended for unbreakable boxes.

I assume that the question text only has one paragraph (with some trickery one could also allow more than one).
The label is typeset in the margin and the number of lines is counted. Also the text is measured by setting it in a \vbox so at the end of the environment we can issue \par and compare the number of lines with that of the label; if it's less, empty one-line paragraphs are generated.
I'd recommend to uncomment the \addvspace lines, but I left them commented to show that the spacing is as expected.
For the label, the trick is to use a smashed top aligned tabular.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{m +b}
 {
  \par
  %\addvspace{\topsep}
  \ysalmon_question_label:n {#1}
  \ysalmon_question_text:n {#2}
  %\addvspace{\topsep}
 }{}

\box_new:N \l__ysalmon_question_text_box
\seq_new:N \l__ysalmon_question_label_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ysalmon_question_text:n
 {
  \vbox_set:Nn \l__ysalmon_question_text_box
   {
    \cs_set:Npn \stepcounter ##1 {}
    \ignorespaces\strut#1
   }
  \ignorespaces\strut#1\par
  \fp_compare:nT
   {% the number of lines rounded up
    ceil ( \box_ht:N \l__ysalmon_question_text_box / \baselineskip,0 )
    <
    \seq_count:N \l__ysalmon_question_label_seq
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \seq_count:N \l__ysalmon_question_label_seq - 
      \fp_eval:n { ceil ( \box_ht:N \l__ysalmon_question_text_box / \baselineskip,0 ) }
     }
     { \nopagebreak \mbox{} \par }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ysalmon_question_label:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__ysalmon_question_label_seq { \\ } {#1}
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]
   {
    \smash
     {
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__ysalmon_question_label_seq \__ysalmon_question_label_do:nn
      \end{tabular}
      \quad
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ysalmon_question_label_do:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 1 } { \bfseries } { \itshape } #2 \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{arfze \\ b}
test with just one line
\end{question}

Text following the question

\begin{question}{arfze\\b}
test test test test test test test testtest test test testtest test test 
testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test
\end{question}

Text following the question

\begin{question}{arfze\\b \\ c}
test test test test test test test testtest test test testtest test test 
testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test
\end{question}

Text following the question

\begin{question}{arfze\\b \\ c}
test test test test test test test testtest test test 
\[
a+b=c
\]
testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test
testtest test test test
\end{question}

Text following the question

\begin{question}{arfze\\b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g}
test test test test test test test testtest test test 
\begin{equation}\label{A}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test
testtest test test test
\end{question}

Text following the question

\end{document}



Thanks, this is nice because it requires only one compilation. However, it relies not only on there being only one paragraph, but also, if I understand correctly, on each line having the same height (so no displaymath, no tikzpicture, etc.).

@ysalmon See edited version

Wow ! Very nice. A enlightening use case of the b spec. This will make it fail if the environment contains verbatim text ; however, I think its use use could be eschewed with\vbox_set:Nw, but then "replaying" the content might be more convoluted.

@ysalmon The b argument doesn't allow verbatim. One could start a \vtop in the begin part, typeset it and then do the measurement. Exercise.
